# How to put numbers between $$ in R?

Tags: r

I want to use `xtable` package for exporting R outputs to LaTex.

Because I want to use a Persian font I should put the numbers between $$.
How can I do this in R?

T tried `as.character`, but xtable doesn't work for it.

Comment: In fact, it would be cleaner to put the numbers inside `\num{…}` (from the `siunitx` package), not `$…$`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the argument `sanitize.text.fuction` in `print.xtable`:

```
df <- data.frame(foo=paste0("$",1:10,"$"))
library("xtable")
print(xtable(df),sanitize.text.function=identity)
```

Gives:

```
% latex table generated in R 2.15.1 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Tue Oct 30 05:44:05 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rl}
  \hline
 & foo \\ 
  \hline
1 & $1$ \\ 
  2 & $2$ \\ 
  3 & $3$ \\ 
  4 & $4$ \\ 
  5 & $5$ \\ 
  6 & $6$ \\ 
  7 & $7$ \\ 
  8 & $8$ \\ 
  9 & $9$ \\ 
  10 & $10$ \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to do this with `xtable`, but I have successfully used the function `latex` in package `Hmisc` with its overwhelming list of parameters with Chinese characters, so I assume this could work with Persian fonts too.